# How to drop NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

#Integer encoding

X = df.drop(labels = ['Category','Rating','Genres','Genres_c'],axis = 1)

y = df.Rating

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30)

model = LinearRegression()

model.fit(X_train,y_train)

Results = model.predict(X_test)

#Creation of results dataframe and addition of first entry

resultsdf = pd.DataFrame()

resultsdf = resultsdf.from_dict(Evaluationmatrix_dict(y_test,Results),orient = 'index')

resultsdf = resultsdf.transpose()

#dummy encoding

X_d = df2.drop(labels = \['Rating','Genres','Category_c','Genres_c'\],axis = 1)
y_d = df2.Rating

X_train_d, X_test_d, y_train_d, y_test_d = train_test_split(X_d, y_d, test_size=0.30)

model_d = LinearRegression()

model_d.fit(X_train_d,y_train_d)

Results_d = model_d.predict(X_test_d)

resultsdf = resultsdf.append(Evaluationmatrix_dict(y_test_d,Results_d, name = 'Linear - Dummy'),ignore_index = True)
```

And I'm getting the following error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-01d839bd8504> in <cell line: 26>()
     24 model_d = LinearRegression()
     25 
---> 26 model_d.fit(X_train_d,y_train_d)
     27 Results_d = model_d.predict(X_test_d)
     28 resultsdf = resultsdf.append(Evaluationmatrix_dict(y_test_d,Results_d, name = 'Linear - Dummy'),ignore_index = True)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype, estimator_name, input_name)
    159                 "#estimators-that-handle-nan-values"
    160             )
--> 161         raise ValueError(msg_err)
    162 
    163 

ValueError: Input X contains NaN.
LinearRegression does not accept missing values encoded as NaN natively. For supervised learning, you might want to consider sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier and Regressor which accept missing values encoded as NaNs natively. Alternatively, it is possible to preprocess the data, for instance by using an imputer transformer in a pipeline or drop samples with missing values. See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html You can find a list of all estimators that handle NaN values at the following page: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#estimators-that-handle-nan-values
```

I know pandas has the dropna method to drop NaN values but Ican't understand how to use that here. Can anybody help?

I have tried writing `X=X.dropna(axis=0, how='any')` below `y=df.Rating`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For a Dataframe, you can use [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html). In the case of your code, to remove NaN values from `X`:

```
X.dropna()
```

This will remove all rows with at least 1 missing value.